# Calling info from an Access database

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

I have created a form that will collect a student's ID number and store that number, along with the time and date into an Access database via a VB application. I have created a second form that displays the Access database table entries. The problem that I am running into is that the information being sent to the database by the application for the time is being stored in a date/time field. It is being sent in short form and that is how the entry displays when the database file itself is opened, but when I display the table through my vb form, it displays like this:
[Full date(today's date) followed by the time entry, should only be short time](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iGH76.jpg)

This is the code that I am using to call the form:

```
Dim mySecondForm As Form2
mySecondForm = Form2
mySecondForm.Show()
```

And this is the code that I am using to display the table:

```
Me.FT_EntriesTableAdapter.Fill(Me.Fit_Track_CopyDataSet.FT_Entries)
```

So what I need to know is, how do I get the time field to just display the short time on form2 like it does in the database?

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: a) `It is being sent in short form` we have no proof of that.  b) what is that control?  A DGV?  if so you can control the formatting by setting the DefaultCellStyle property c) it is not too late to read [Ask] and also take the [Tour]

Comment: you are missing `New` in that first line: `Dim mySecondForm As New Form2` then you dont need the second line and are no longer using default form instances

Comment: Thank you, @Plutonix. That was what I needed. I set the DefaultCellStyle property and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, do what Plutonix said.

```
mySecondForm.DataGridView1.Columns("Time").DefaultCellStyle.Format = "t"
```

"DataGridView1" is the default name for a new DataGridView object; change as needed.

Have a look at [MS's documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1(v=vs.110).aspx) for more info on Date/Time format strings.